# RoR with simple_form: Automatically assign nil to 'empty' attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

When an empty field is submitted through a form, the attribute then becomes '', as in whitespace, yet I would think it should be nil?

Is it possible to keep attributes as nil if they are updated as empty?

I did find this gem:

https://github.com/grosser/clear_empty_attributes

But I don't see how this hasn't been addressed by now (that gem is 3 years old) and perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :clear_empty_attrs

  def clear_empty_attrs
    changes.each { |k, v| write_attribute(k, nil) if v.last.blank? }
  end
end
```

Comment: Because I then have to add that to every model.

Comment: Add it dynamically to your models - for example in an initializer.

Comment: That is exactly what the gem does. I was thinking perhaps Rails had introduced a config for this by now. Thanks for the help.